# c++ netbeans shows syntax errors, but compiles and runs correctly

Tags: c++, netbeans, syntax-error, mingw

I installed NeatBeans IDE 8.1 fresh for C++ development and began a blank new project. The code for the project is shown below. The code within the editor shows a `syntax error`, although when building, **THE CODE RUNS PERFECTLY FINE**.

[image: Code]

Although `iostream` is imported correctly, and I can view `iostream.h` by clicking on it, std seems to be completely undefined. In fact, I cannot use any library without it showing a syntax error. I realize that having an `std` in front of `cout` is redundant, since I am supposed to be `using namespace std`, but I just wanted to show that it is not just the namespace. I am using a 64 bit MinGW compiler as my configuration as pictured below.

[image: include directories]

I have tried using all solutions online, such as `Reparse project`, but that and others do not seem to help rectify this issue. How can I make the editor show no syntax errors and build correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem. I used to fix it by doing a "Run -> clean and build project".